# How to make multiple transaction in web3js

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I know web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction() of web3js which is used to send transaction and in return gives us transaction hash. But when I want to make multiple transaction in a loop. It gives me errors like

```
1 - Transaction known
2 - duplicate transaction
3 - error
```

So how can I make multiple transaction for sending tokens which can run in loop. The main problem causing this issue is nounce(transaction count of last mined transaction). The transaction is not mined and we give them multiple transaction hence we get same nounce results in getting all these errors. But there is some way for sending multiple transaction. Because when I do the same task in myetherwallet or metamask, it can send multiple transaction.

Comment: increase nonce work well but you need use[`web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1763#issuecomment-403727592) not [web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#id67)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increment the nonce with each transaction you send.

Comment: What if any of the transaction fails in between. Means 5 worked 6 didn't and 7 worked again

Comment: The nonce still needs to be increased, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Increasing nounce is not working. The transaction is not added in blockchain. In etherscan I am getting message as the transaction is not found. Though I received transaction hash in web3js.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information in your question (e.g. your code).

Comment: Refer this link

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24828/how-to-send-erc20-token-using-web3-api

In Web3js I am running a forEach loop of address and value to be transacted.
          
web3.eth.getTransactionCount().then((lastTransactionCount)=>{
        object.forEach(function(obj,index){
          var a = obj.address;
          var b = obj.value;
          newCount = lastTransactionCOunt + index
          web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction()
}) 

I hope the above code's logic helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how that question relates? Neither the question nor any of the answers seem to be from you. Did you copy code from something on that page? If so, what? Please add the code to your question.

Comment: The code you shared looks incomplete. (Notably, the parameters to `sendSignedTransaction` are missing.) Please also share what kind of node you're connecting to.

Comment: It looks like the first element of the array has a `count` of `1`, so all the nonces will be one too high?

Comment: Actually getTransactionCount returns 43 means transaction ID from 0 to 42 perhaps I think so

Comment: Currently its working. Couldn't understand why. But its working. Probably it would be nouce thing